# Proof equation expectation 0

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Consider two random variables $X,Y$ in a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,P)$ with $\mathcal F\subset \mathcal A$ a sigma-algebra. In this case is $X$ square integrable.
I have to show that $$E[(X-E(X\mid \mathcal F))E(X\mid \mathcal F)]=0$$ but I don't see how.

Comment: where is $Y$ in all that? :-)

Comment: Have edited my question :)

Comment: I still can't see $Y$

Comment: It was too much information, it doens't appear in the equation to be proven.

Comment: @RoosJansen better remove $Y$ from the question, it can lead to misunderstanding or confusion.

Comment: You could try iterated expectations:  $E[Y] = E[E[Y|\mathcal{F}]]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes from the definition. You know that $E[X \mid \mathcal F]$ is $\mathcal F$-measurable.

So if you rewrite the thesis to be proven as

$$E[X E(X \mid \mathcal F)] = E[E(X \mid \mathcal F) E(X \mid \mathcal F)]$$

you see that is true thanks to the definition of conditional expectation. That is the expectation of  $X$ times a random variable which is $\mathcal F$ measurable (in this case $E[X \mid \mathcal F]$) is the same of the expectation of $E[X \mid \mathcal F]$ times the previous $\mathcal F$ measurable random variable (again $E[X \mid \mathcal F]$)